# Checkbox MaterializeCSS label

Tags: html, css, materialize

Preciso construir esta estrutura da imagem, mas não consigo fazer com que o input radio fique em cima da imagem usando MaterializeCSS. Alguém conhece alguma solução? Abraço!

Ex do HTML:

```
<p>
   <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" />
   <label for="test1"><img src="" alt="" class=""></label>
</p>
```

[image: Imagem de ex.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara com essa estrutura de HTML com a imagem dentro da `label` ficou meio complicado... mas deu certo! Foi preciso ajustar os `position` nas classes do `label` `::before` e `::after` Talvez vc precise fazer um ajuste no `top` do `::after` pra ficar ajustado com suas imagens, mas deixei o *comment* no código ok

Veja o exemplo funcionando.

```css
.custom-radio [type="radio"]+label:before, .custom-radio [type="radio"]+label:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin: 4px auto;
    position: initial;
}
.custom-radio [type="radio"]+label:after {
    position: relative;
    top: -82px !important; /* ajuste a altura conforma o tamanho da imagem */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <p class="custom-radio">
        <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" />
        <label for="test1"><img src="http://placeskull.com/80/50" alt="" class=""></label>

        <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test2" />
        <label for="test2"><img src="http://placeskull.com/81/50" alt="" class=""></label>

        <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test4" />
        <label for="test4"><img src="http://placeskull.com/79/50" alt="" class=""></label>
     </p>
```

Comment: Mtoo obrigado!!